# Which of these groups $S_3, S_4, D_4$, and $Q_8$ are the semidirect product of its cyclic subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If I take $H = \{(), (1 2)\}$ and $N = \{(), (1 2 3), (1 3 2)\}$, then $S_3 = HN$ and the intersection of $H$ and $N$ is trivial so $S_3$ becomes a semidirect of its cyclic subgroups.

I don't know how to deal with the other three groups and would kindly ask for a little help with answering these.

Comment: For $Q_8$ see [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411935/smallest-example-of-a-group-that-is-not-isomorphic-to-a-cyclic-group-a-direct-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Fulfill details:

$$\begin{align*}&S_3\cong A_3\rtimes C_2\;,\;\;C_n=\text{ the cyclic group with $\;n\;$ elements}\\{}\\
&S_4\cong A_4\rtimes C_2 \ldots\text{ but is $\;A_4\;$  cyclic...}?\\{}\\
&D_4\cong C_4\rtimes C_2\\{}\\
&Q_8\cong Q_8\;\ldots\ldots\text{ (what is the intersection of any two subgroups of this group?)}\end{align*}$$

Comment: @amWhy Good catch, thanks. Edited

Comment: No problem ....

Comment: A4 is not cyclic, so S4 is not a semidirect product of its cyclic subgroups. D4 is and in the case of Q8, the intersection is {1,-1} so it isn't a semidirect product either? I s

Comment: @Maria Precisely so. Good.